# ProgressDialog won't work correctly with long calculations

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have tried a lot of things to get this ProgressDialog to work correctly, but I have still not gotten it 100%. I have basically come to two separate dead ends equally as close to the final goal.

First, I tried creating an extra `Thread` and using `runOnUiThread`. This results in the Dialog `showing` and `dismissing` at the proper times that I want it to, but the spinner does not spin. It sits stationary and never adjusts.

```
readButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.readButton );
    readButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog( Waves.this );  
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pd.setMessage("Reading...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);            
            pd.show( );

            Thread export = new Thread() {  
                 public void run() {
                        if( myService.getState() != 3 ) {
                            runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Log.i( "myService", "12222" ); 
                                    myService.setHandler( mHandler );
                                    myService.connect( MainMenu.previousDevice, true );
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    readWaves();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                 mHandler.obtainMessage(MainMenu.READ_FINISHED ).sendToTarget();
                 pd.dismiss();
                 }
            };
            export.start();
            }
    });
```

The next thing I have tried to do is use an `AsyncTask`. From what I have found all over the internet and SO this looks like the way to go. The spinner starts off spinning and my code begins working, but after a short amount of time my application leaves the current activity and completely restarts. The `LogCat` is shown below but it does not show me any errors.

```
 readButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.readButton );
    readButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new readPage().execute( null, null, null );
            }
    });


 public class readPage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog pdia;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
                pdia = new ProgressDialog( Waves.this);
                pdia.setMessage("Reading...");
                pdia.setCancelable( false );
                pdia.show();
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            pdia.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i( "ASYNC", "2" );
            if( myService.getState() != 3 ) {
                myService.setHandler( mHandler );
                myService.connect( MainMenu.previousDevice, true );
            } else {
                readWaves();
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Here is the `LogCat`. The first line shown is the last thing in the `LogCat` that is part of my code. I haven't checked what happens at this line because it always works, just not with this `AsyncTask` implemented. The last line has an `Main Menu  ++ ON CREATE ++` entry which is when my application restarts.

```
01-07 18:23:27.738: W/NATIVE CODE(28111): After SetBaud
01-07 18:23:29.777: I/dalvikvm(28111): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
01-07 18:23:30.781: W/dalvikvm(28111): threadid=4: spin on suspend #1 threadid=9 (pcf=0)
01-07 18:23:30.781: D/dalvikvm(28111): Temporarily moving tid 28128 to fg (was 0)
01-07 18:23:30.781: D/dalvikvm(28111): Temporarily raised priority on tid 28128 (10 -> 0)
01-07 18:23:31.527: W/dalvikvm(28111): threadid=4: spin on suspend #2 threadid=9 (pcf=3)
01-07 18:23:31.531: I/dalvikvm(28111): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
01-07 18:23:31.531: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050f730 self=0x117d60
01-07 18:23:31.531: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | sysTid=28114 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
01-07 18:23:31.531: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-07 18:23:31.531: I/dalvikvm(28111): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
01-07 18:23:31.531: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40559388 self=0x2e1a10
01-07 18:23:31.531: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | sysTid=28128 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3243272
01-07 18:23:31.925: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.GetWavesJava(Native Method)
01-07 18:23:31.933: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves.readWaves(Waves.java:365)
01-07 18:23:31.937: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves.access$0(Waves.java:350)
01-07 18:23:31.941: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves$readPage.doInBackground(Waves.java:323)
01-07 18:23:31.945: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves$readPage.doInBackground(Waves.java:1)
01-07 18:23:31.949: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-07 18:23:31.957: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-07 18:23:31.960: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-07 18:23:31.964: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-07 18:23:31.968: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-07 18:23:31.972: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-07 18:23:32.734: W/dalvikvm(28111): threadid=4: spin on suspend #3 threadid=9 (pcf=3)
01-07 18:23:32.734: I/dalvikvm(28111): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
01-07 18:23:32.734: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050f730 self=0x117d60
01-07 18:23:32.734: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | sysTid=28114 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
01-07 18:23:32.734: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-07 18:23:32.734: I/dalvikvm(28111): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
01-07 18:23:32.734: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40559388 self=0x2e1a10
01-07 18:23:32.734: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | sysTid=28128 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3243272
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.GetWavesJava(Native Method)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves.readWaves(Waves.java:365)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves.access$0(Waves.java:350)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves$readPage.doInBackground(Waves.java:323)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves$readPage.doInBackground(Waves.java:1)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-07 18:23:32.859: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-07 18:23:32.863: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-07 18:23:33.613: W/dalvikvm(28111): threadid=4: spin on suspend #4 threadid=9 (pcf=3)
01-07 18:23:33.613: I/dalvikvm(28111): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
01-07 18:23:33.613: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050f730 self=0x117d60
01-07 18:23:33.613: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | sysTid=28114 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
01-07 18:23:33.613: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-07 18:23:33.613: I/dalvikvm(28111): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40559388 self=0x2e1a10
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | sysTid=28128 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3243272
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.GetWavesJava(Native Method)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves.readWaves(Waves.java:365)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves.access$0(Waves.java:350)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves$readPage.doInBackground(Waves.java:323)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves$readPage.doInBackground(Waves.java:1)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-07 18:23:33.617: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-07 18:23:34.367: W/dalvikvm(28111): threadid=4: spin on suspend #5 threadid=9 (pcf=3)
01-07 18:23:34.367: I/dalvikvm(28111): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
01-07 18:23:34.367: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050f730 self=0x117d60
01-07 18:23:34.367: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | sysTid=28114 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40559388 self=0x2e1a10
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   | sysTid=28128 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3243272
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.GetWavesJava(Native Method)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves.readWaves(Waves.java:365)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves.access$0(Waves.java:350)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves$readPage.doInBackground(Waves.java:323)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at my.eti.commander.Waves$readPage.doInBackground(Waves.java:1)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-07 18:23:34.371: I/dalvikvm(28111):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-07 18:23:35.253: E/MainMenu(28151): +++ ON CREATE +++
```

**EDIT:**

I also want to add I have tried using `.hide()` instead of `.dismiss()`, but I don't think that that is the problem. I create a new instance of the `ProgressDialog` every time it is used.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your readWaves() method? It looks to me like the issue is in there, that the application is crashing because of Thread issues and isn't related directly to the ProgressDialog

Comment: Well I'm doing a whole lot. I'm using the NDK and JNI to call back and forth between my application and an existing C library. Basically, I call readWaves() which calls a function in my C library. The C library then uses the Bluetooth stream from the java side to send and receive a lot of bits. Depending on the bits received variables in the C library are set to different values. Then after readWaves() I update my UI by checking the C library to see what the updated values are.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to run your long calculation process in background.You can show your progress dialog on `OnPreExecute()`. When the calculation get finished this async method will cal `onPostExecute()` where you can cancel the Progress Dialog. You calculation coding goes inside `doInBackground()`.

```
public class LongCaluclation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{  
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{  
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog.setMessage("Calculation in progress please wait...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

} 
@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
 }

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

{ 
      //Post Execute
       dialog.cancel();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

  // Your operation..Dont Edit Any Views here

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: This wasn't really an answer to my question, but thanks. From what I can tell the only difference between this is my code is calling `.cancel()` as opposed to `.dismiss()` in the `onPostExecute()` method. I tried changing this in my code but I got the same result. The code gets to a certain point and then restarts the application completely.

Comment: @juice at what point it get restarts have you identified that

Comment: No. It is deep within my native code. I do not think it is a problem with my native code as it works without any of this implemented, and also works with the thread implementation I showed first.